# Windows用で作成したC#プロジェクトがMacOSでは画面が崩れている

Tags: c#, windows, macos, .net, .net-core

WindowsOSでC#でプロジェクトを作成しました。
Mac用アプリも作成したいと思いVisual Studio for Macをインストールして、Windowsで動作していたプロジェクトをビルドしました。
Macで見つからないライブラリなど削除し、「system.NotSupportedException」をスローする部分はコメントアウトしました。
ビルドが通ったのでデバックを実行したところ「mono64が予期しない理由で終了しました。」
と表示されました。
カスタム構成の詳細設定でアーキテクチャを32ビットに変更した際にはクラッシュしなくなったのですが、画面に表示しているボタンの文字列が崩れており、描画の更新もうまく行われておりません。
ボタンは「System.Windows.Forms.Button()」を使用しています。
Graphics.DrawImageおよびGraphics.DrawStringで描画したものは正しく表示されています。
WindowsからMac用に直す際に必要なライブラリが欠けている、もしくは壊れているのが原因なのでしょうか？

Comment: 古いですが、こんな記事が参考になるのでは？[XamarinでWindows / Mac OSX 両対応のデスクトップアプリを作る](https://qiita.com/okajima/items/8ca53ff00a825f28dbc6)

Comment: コメントアウトした部分に原因があるように思います。Macでビルドできるように編集したコードをWindows側に戻してきてビルド・実行は試しましたか？

Comment: Xamarinを詳しく調べてみます。
ライブラリなど両プラットフォームで互換してくれるのでしょうか？

Comment: Macでビルド出来るように編集したコードはWindows側で正しく動作することを確認しました。